# Como encerrar uma conversa aberta ou um grupo?

Tags: suporte

Como fechar um grupo de conversa depois de aberto? Até hoje não consegui observar esta opção, e da vez que criei um grupo, teve de passar alguns dias para ele sumir.

Desculpem a ignorância.

Comment: Você está falando de um *chat*?

Comment: Isso mesmo @bigow.

Comment: Salas de chat inativas são automaticamente apagadas depois de um tempo (1 mês, acho).